# Validate upon object state change (i.e. draft->not-draft) c# Rule/Validator

Tags: validation, .net-core

Say I have a complicated object with loads of properties that I won't fill out straight away. So I can save incomplete/invalid objects. I want to validate the object when the user reckons it should no-longer be a draft.

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo (){_state =  new Draft(this);}

  // this and a whole bunch of other properties have higher validation requirements 
  // when not just a draft
  public string Name {get; set;} 
  public DateTime? SomeDate{get; set;} 
  // ... more properties

  private CustomState _state;
  public CustomState State {get{return _state;}}
  public void StopBeingADraft(){ CustomState.StopBeingADraft(); }
}
```

Attribute validation won't help me here as I can save the object in a draft state with `obj.Name=null` but once I call `obj.StopBeingADraft()` I want a list of errors saying whats wrong with all the properties like

I've been searching online for with various word combinations and not finding what I need I just need the right phrase to search for Validator/Rule seems like a

Or should I just be saving them as completely different objects like

```
class Draft
{
  string Name{get; set;}
  NotDraft StopBeingADraft(){}
}
class NotDraft
{
  [Required]
  string Name{get; set;}
}
```

Which seems a lot much just to use inbuilt validation. Want a net core solution, this doesn't seem like the most uncommon case, just maybe I'm thinking about it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to use fluent validation...
https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

```
public class FooValidator: AbstractValidator<Foo> 
{
  public FooValidator() 
  {
    RuleFor(o=> o.Name).NotEmpty();
    ///.. etc    
  }
}
```

usage:

```
 var obj = new Foo();
 var validator = new FooValidator();
 ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(obj);

 bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
 IList<ValidationFailure> failures = results.Errors;
```

Was hoping to use net core to do it without another library, this solution is called when I want it and doesn't mess with model state which I need for how the code flow works at the moment, would welcome other ways to solve it. Seems like I missed something.